# Prove that $\overline{\{x\in X: ||x-a||<\delta\}}\subset\{x\in X: ||x-a||\leq\delta\}.$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, solution-verification, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed linear space. I was trying to prove $\overline{\{x\in X: ||x-a||<\delta\}}\subset\{x\in X: ||x-a||\leq\delta\}.$

My attempt:- Let $y \in \overline{\{x\in X: ||x-a||<\delta\}}\implies \exists$ sequence $\{y_n\}\subset \{x\in X: ||x-a||<\delta\}$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty}y_n=y.$ That is for a given $\epsilon>0, \exists N\in \mathbb N: \forall n\ge N\implies ||y_n-y||<\epsilon.$

Consider $\forall n\geq N\implies ||y-a||\leq||y-y_n||+||y_n-a||<\epsilon+\delta.$

I wish to prove $||y-a||\leq \delta.$
I tried to prove using the method of contradiction. Assume  $||y-a||>\delta$ and ( $\forall n\geq N\implies ||y-a||<\epsilon+\delta.)$ are true. That is we get $\forall n\geq N\implies \delta<||y-a||<\epsilon+\delta.$ That is $\forall n\geq N\implies 0<||y-a||-\delta<\epsilon.$  Let $\epsilon=(||y-a||-\delta)/2\implies \exists N'\in \mathbb N': \forall n\ge N\implies0<||y-a||-\delta<(||y-a||-\delta)/2.$ Which is a contradiction. Hence, $||y-a||\leq \delta.$

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Could be done straightforward and shorter basing on the same inequality as in OP $\|y-a\|\le \|y-y_n\|+\|y_n-a\|< \|y-y_n\|+\delta$ Take the limit of the right hand side.

Comment: Thanks. actually, I wish to familariase this type of proofs. different proof techniques means different arrows in my arrow holder. :)